# Which action hooks are available for the wildfly cartridge on openshift?

Tags: openshift, wildfly

I am trying to hook into the pre start hooks to set some settings before starting the wildfly server on openshift?

But it is hard to find out which action hooks are available for the wildfly cartridge. 
I have found the following documentation: http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_user_guide.html#action-hooks

And i have added a 'pre_start' and a 'pre_restart' command with an 'echo', so i can see if the  action hook is called, but when i push something to openshift, i do not so my 'echo's' from the push output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have marked them as executable (chmod +x) when you add them into your git repository.

Answer (score 2):

All the usual hooks are supported: http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_user_guide.html#action-hooks

Make sure they are executable.

Comment: The problem was indeed that they were not executable.